# Win Scheduled Task cannot see PrintService

Tags: java, windows, printing, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a java code that sends PDF files to printers. 
Java code goes something like this:

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

public class PrintPdf {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

public void print(String pdfFile, String printer, int copies) throws Exception {

    PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    PDDocument document = null;

    try
    {
        document = PDDocument.load( pdfFile );
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PrintService[] printServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
        PrintService myService = null;

        if (printServices.length > 0)
        {
            for(PrintService service : printServices) {
                if(service.getName().toLowerCase().contains(printer.toLowerCase())) {
                    myService = service;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (myService == null) {
                throw new Exception("Printer not found " + printer);
            } else {
                logger.info("Printer found " + myService.getName());
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("No print services found");
        } 

        printJob.setPrintService(myService);
        printJob.setCopies(copies);
        document.silentPrint( printJob );

    }
    finally {
        if( document != null ) {
            document.close();
        }
    }   
}
```

This java is called from batch file. I've scheduled a windows task to run the file every X minutes. Scheduled Task is run with a user that has admin rights. All this is run on a Windows 2003 server.
Printers are set up using a TCP/IP address.

The problem: When the user is logged in, the Task runs and can send PDF files to the printers. 
When the user is not logged in, the Task runs but java returns an error:

`java.awt.print.PrinterException: Invalid name of PrintService`

Java program successfully lists available Print Services in the loop, just before the print command, but for some reason is not able to print the document while the user is not logged in.

Could anyone, please, give me some advice on what might be the problem here?

EDIT: 
Exception occurs in the line:

```
printJob.setPrintService(myService);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to upgrade the existing java on the OS from version 6u45 to 7u21.